# Grouping in Teradata on multiple dimensions

Tags: group-by, teradata, analysis, cube

I have been using the extended group by functionality of cubing data to view it at various dimensions. Apparently cube restricts the number of variables that can be cubed (not more than 10) which is not mentioned anywhere in the documentation. I need an alternative in Teradata for this using which data can be rolled up at multiple levels without any limitations on the number of variables being used. Please help :)

Answer (score 1):

It's [clearly documented in the manuals](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_15_10/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1146_151K/ch01.021.136.html#ww20546827) that you can't have more than eight columns for a  `CUBE`:

*"You cannot specify more than 8 columns"*

And those eight columns already result in 256 levels of aggregation. If you need more you can easily run multiple SELECTs.